# tinyMCE 4.0.5 ObjectResizeStart doesn't work

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

I have **latest version of tinyMCE** I need to use this function:

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4:event.tinymce.Editor.ObjectResizeStart

to prevent image resizing when I'm in **read mode** because in Chrome images and tables can be rezised even when I'm saying  `readonly: true`.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable resizing with

```
object_resizing : false
```